# Huawei P8 Lite fragment blank screen issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, freeze, huawei-mobile-services

I've a problem on my application when I test it on *Huawei P8 Lite device* (on other devices it works very nice): on MainActivity i created a bottom bar with five buttons to replace four fragments with FrameLayout (the fifth button is used to open another activity) and navigate with backstack from/to fragments.

When I run app on Huawei device **all fragments are loaded partially** (recycler view items are not loaded) and the **view is like freezing**.

Here, three strange behavior:

1. if I try to scroll the items in the recycler view (no scrolling effect showing) and click on one of them, the behavior is correct (on tap I open another activity);
2. if I tap on one of other buttons in the bottom bar of MainActivity
   the fragment is replaced but the view is freezing (and same behavior
   of point 1);
3. if I re-run app with Instant Run on Android Studio
   on the same Activity, the fragment draws the element in the recycler
   view and if I try to scroll it works perfect!

It seems that the items are drawn when I replace fragment, I see them before change fragment.
Very very strange.

Please help me before I split the device in two pieces!

Comment: Sharing the sample code snippets will help to assist you..

Comment: Were you able to solve this?